# Bot Framework retrieve user address from Cosmos DB in order to send a Proactive message NODE JS

Tags: node.js, database, azure, botframework, azure-cosmosdb

I have never worked with Cosmos DB so I don't really know how the connection works. I did search for answers for a long time, but didn't find any. In the documentation, I only found how to CONNECT the Bot with my Cosmos DB, which I indeed did.

The answer I need:

- **what is the code to retrieve the user Address I have saved to my DB when user registeres (`//REGISTER`)**

-- In `//TEST` I have a simple code to send the proactive message, right now, as you can see, it sends only to the current state of address in the App. Instead I need to retrieve it from my Azure Cosmos DB where I save the users.

[***HERE IS THE LINK FOR MY BOT CODE***](https://pastebin.com/3L08Rju7)

*I am very grateful in advance to anyone who will at least try to answer. =)*

**Inline code:**

```
var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var fs = require('fs');

//RESTIFY SETUP

var https_options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./herobot.hero-translating.com.key'), //on current folder
    certificate: fs.readFileSync('./herobot.hero-translating.com.crt')
};

var server = restify.createServer(https_options);
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 8081, function() {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
});

//BOT CONNECTOR
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: 'HIDDEN',
    appPassword: 'HIDDEN'
});

//COSMOS DB CONNECTION

var azure = require('botbuilder-azure');

var documentDbOptions = {
    host: 'https://HIDDEN.documents.azure.com:443/',
    masterKey: 'HIDDEN',
    database: 'HIDDEN',
    collection: 'HIDDEN',
};

var docDbClient = new azure.DocumentDbClient(documentDbOptions);
var cosmosStorage = new azure.AzureBotStorage({ gzipData: false }, docDbClient);

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
bot.set('storage', cosmosStorage);

server.post('/api/smessages', connector.listen());

//DIALOGS

String.prototype.contains = function(content) {
    return this.indexOf(content) !== -1;
};

bot.dialog('/', function(session) {

    function sendProactiveMessage(address) {
        var msg = new builder.Message().address(address);
        msg.text('Test message.');
        msg.textLocale('en-US');
        bot.send(msg);
    }

    const userText = session.message.text.toLowerCase();

    String.prototype.is = function() {
        const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        const text = userText;
        for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
            if (text.includes(args[i])) return true;
        return false;
    };



    //Greeting  
    if (userText.is('hello', 'hi', 'good morning', 'good afternoon', 'hey'))
        session.send(`Hello.`);

    //Thanks    
    else if (userText.is('thank you', 'thanks', 'thx'))
        session.send(`You are welcome!`);

    //REGISTER
    else if (userText.is('register')) {
        var savedAddress = session.message.address;
        session.userData.savedAddress = savedAddress;
        //REGISTERED MESSAGE
        session.send("*Congratulations! You are now registered in our network! (goldmedal)*");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(savedAddress));
    }

    //TEST
    else if (userText.is('test')) {
        sendProactiveMessage(savedAddress);
    }

    //Unrecognized messages    
    else
        session.send(`I don't understand your input.`);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`documentdb`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/documentdb)? Here is a link to a [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-nodejs-application#_Toc395783180) on how to use the package in a web app code.

Comment: Also, some would say this is a incomplete or poor-form question, as by looking through your code, it doesn't look like you attempted to create a connection to your CosmosDB for your proactive message. It only contains a CosmosDB connection for managing your Bot's State. Stack Overflow frowns on questions without at least a shown solution to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is sending proactive messages to Users from Cosmos DB.

When you **REGISTER** a user in your code, you saved *session.message.address* to session users's userData. You can observe this data in your Cosmos DB.
Running on my bot emulator I will see 3 documents (min) in my Cosmos DB/botdocs/botdata:

1. **default-user**,userData
2. [conversationId],conversationData
3. [conversationId],**default-user**

**default-user** is essentially the User ID of the bot. And you saved the address *(session.userData.savedAddress = savedAddress;)* in userData.

To send proactive message, you simply need to query the Cosmos DB for documents like (1.) with savedAddress and send message.

You can refer to my [code](https://github.com/helenlo319/BotFramework_ProactiveMessage). The current trigger for this sample is using the timer after 5 seconds, which will send proactive message to ALL registered user. You can change the query to select particular user or change the trigger to http requests.